# Dockerbuild failing whilst following python language tutorial from docker site

Tags: python, docker

I'm following along the language specific guide from docker for python https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/ however my build is failing due to pip3 unable to find distributions for a number of my dependencies in requirements.txt.

For further info I am using an ubuntu 20.04 image on virtualbox as a dev environment and have basically only installed flask other than standard python packages.

pip3 installs the requirements.txt fine when run from my terminal but for somereason when done in the Dockerfile fails.

any help greatly appreciated.

The Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

The error message:

```
error =ERROR: No matching distribution found for Brlapi==0.7.0
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
```

Output of requirements.txt which is simply the result of

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

---

```
- blinker==1.4 
- Brlapi==0.7.0 
- certifi==2019.11.28 
- chardet==3.0.4
- click==8.0.1 
- colorama==0.4.3 
- cryptography==2.8 
- cupshelpers==1.0
- dbus-python==1.2.16 
- defer==1.0.6 
- distro==1.4.0
- distro-info===0.23ubuntu1 
- entrypoints==0.3 
- Flask==2.0.1
- greenlet==0.4.15 
- httplib2==0.14.0 
- idna==2.8 
- itsdangerous==2.0.1
-  Jinja2==3.0.1 
- keyring==18.0.1 
- language-selector==0.1
- launchpadlib==1.10.13 
- lazr.restfulclient==0.14.2 
- lazr.uri==1.0.3
-  louis==3.12.0 
- macaroonbakery==1.3.1 
- MarkupSafe==2.0.1 
- msgpack==0.6.2
 - netifaces==0.10.4 
- oauthlib==3.1.0 
- olefile==0.46 
- pbr==5.6.0
- pexpect==4.6.0 
- Pillow==7.0.0 
- protobuf==3.6.1 
- pycairo==1.16.2
- pycups==1.9.73 
- PyGObject==3.36.0 
- PyJWT==1.7.1 
- pymacaroons==0.13.0
- PyNaCl==1.3.0 
- pynvim==0.4.1 
- pyRFC3339==1.1
- python-apt==2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.6 
- python-dateutil==2.7.3
-  python-debian===0.1.36ubuntu1 
- pytz==2019.3 
- pyxdg==0.26 
- PyYAML==5.3.1
- reportlab==3.5.34 
- requests==2.22.0 
- requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
- SecretStorage==2.3.1 
- simplejson==3.16.0 
- six==1.14.0
- ssh-import-id==5.10 
- style==1.1.0 
- systemd-python==234
- testresources==2.0.1 
- ubuntu-advantage-tools==27.2
- ubuntu-drivers-common==0.0.0 
- ufw==0.36 
- unattended-upgrades==0.1
- update==0.0.1 
- urllib3==1.25.8 
- wadllib==1.3.3 
- Werkzeug==2.0.1
- xkit==0.0.0
```

Comment: Please share your dependencies and what you're running..

Comment: It is a very common problem in the python world.

Comment: Hello. It would be more helpful if you showed what your Dockerfile looks like instead of the list of packages in your requirements.txt file. Also, is it erring on all packages or just a subset? What is the exact error message(s) you are seeing?

Comment: @idjaw i've added it but it's the exact same as in the docker tutorial. if i remove the named dependency above some other dependency throws an error, if i remove all that it pip can't find then the setup of the others fail. if i run pip3 install outside of docker it works fine.

Comment: Where is this `Brlapi` package from? I can't install it and doesn't seem to be on pypi.

Comment: @idjaw no idea, the only package i've install on this machine is flask, the rest came with ubuntu20.04. i also didn't know what it was so removed it from requirements.txt but then another throws an error.
Edit: on further inspection it seems to be a debian python package used by other linux programmes. brlapi is used in orca which is used by ubuntu-desktop apparantly

Comment: @PatrickLong. I can understand how they were trying to make things easier with just dumping your local Python packages in to a requirements file. But, it unfortunately risks causing issues you're facing. I suggest tweaking things a bit. Replace your `requirements.txt` file with just this line: `Flask==2.0.1`. And continue the tutorial again. Just to make sure I wasn't crazy, I tried it out, and I think it should work.

Comment: @idjaw ahh, of course, in many ways thats more simple than what they were recommending. for reference i tried adding in a apt install line in the docker file of the debian packages but to no avail. thanks for the help!

Comment: @PatrickLong No problem. Glad you got past that. I'm going to see if there is an open issue for that on their GitHub. It's quite an error prone step to add in a tutorial. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, I will explain the issue and solution here as discussed from the comments.

The problem is to no fault of the OP, but the tutorial going through an error prone step by having readers perform a global dump of their Python packages in to `requirements.txt`. This can be seen in the tutorial here:

https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/#sample-application

Specifically this line:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Since this is in your global Python scope and not inside a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) where you will have a more contained and smaller list of packages, you will most likely get quite the long list of Python packages being dumped in to that file. This also goes against how you should be building Docker images in the first place. But, understandably it is not the main scope of this tutorial.

The error that OP received was from not being able to find the `Brlapi` package when building the Docker image. This was easily reproduced on my end, as I could not install that package manually myself either and reproduced the error in the Docker build process as well.

The solution is rather easy. Instead of performing a global dump of your packages, which in general is not wise to do in the first place, the problematic line can be refined to be more specific on what you want to dump in that `requirements.txt` file. More specifically, replace this line:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

to this:

```
pip freeze | grep Flask > requirements.txt
```

The `grep` will match on `Flask` and then dump that to `requirements.txt`. At the very least what this will do (even if it happens to match multiple lines) is only dump a very small subset of packages to that requirements.txt file which should significantly reduce (or remove) the chance for that error. Let us assume it is the only match found, your requirements.txt file should look something like:

```
Flask==2.0.1
```

## Use a Virtual Environment instead!

The tutorial does not mention to do this, and while it is understandable in wanting to avoid more complexity in the tutorial, using a virtual environment to perform these steps will not require any changes in the steps provided in the tutorial. In fact, when working with Python, it is strongly recommended to *always* work inside a virtual environment. When you do not, you are working within a single scope where all your packages will be installed. If you work on multiple different projects you will start to notice that your packages can clash and cause unwanted side effects to your code. As linked above, you can read about virtual environments here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Moving back within context of the [Docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/#sample-application)

When you are about to start following the steps, kick off a virtual environment so you contain this tutorial in its own virtual Python space. For the sake of the tutorial, I suggest putting the Virtual Environment away from the directory that the tutorial will be using. So, do this:

```
cd ~/some/path
python3 -m venv my_venv
source my_venv/bin/activate
```

So, the second line will install a virtual environment for you called `my_venv` (typically it is very common to name it `venv`, but for the sake of this explanation I wanted to separate the words to avoid confusion).

The third line activates your virtual environment and now any python command you use will be within context of that virtual environment. If you go ahead and do a `pip freeze` you should see nothing come up. You are now in a new and clean Python environment.

Remember, however. Once you do not want to be in that context anymore, simply run:

```
deactivate
```

If you do not, then for the duration of your shell session (until you close the shell window you are using) you will be in that environment.

If you follow the virtual environment steps, and then go through the tutorial, you don't actually have to change any lines of code in there since the original problematic line:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

will be scoped to your virtual environment and only grab the packages that were installed in that environment. So, now your `requirements.txt` file should look like this:

```
click==8.0.1
Flask==2.0.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1
```

These are the packages that `Flask` installs and is the only thing installed in this environment. This is also how you want to build your Docker images in general. You always want to build them as light as possible and with the minimum packages/tooling required to run your image.